# WSL Bugs and Problems

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

it is for a while I am working with WSL in win 10 just for testing.
it is really bad. lots of problems.
for example, most daemons are dead and you can not start them or you can nor reboot WSL when you are in the terminal. or this one:

```
sudo reboot -f

Rebooting.
Failed to reboot: Invalid argument
Failed to reboot: Invalid argument
```

or this one:

```
sudo systemctl status nginx.service

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

do you have similar experiences?
what is your solution?

thank you

Comment: Just a heads-up that you are likely receiving a number of downvotes for several reasons.  First, you seem to be blaming the software, when it's apparent that you just haven't taken the time to learn how to use it properly.  Also, this is a duplicate of several other questions that you should have been able to find had you followed the recommendations in the "How to ask a good question" guidance, specifically [Search and Research](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Did you search for *WSL systemd* or *WSL system has not been booted with systemd* or *WSL reboot*?

Answer (score 2):

Systemd is not operational in WSL as per https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8036 and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/994.
For most applications however, you should be able to interface with them directly. To check if a process is running, use `ps`, to quit the shell, use `exit`.

Please also give https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a read.